# Find a particular solution of a nonhomogenous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a particular solution to $y''-2y' + y= {e^{px}}$

where p is any real constant.

My attempt/idea is as follows:

Since $Y_p$ is ${e^{px}}$ and it appears in the complementary solution, $Y_c$ is $c_1{e^x} + c_2x{e^x}$ , we will have to multiply $Y_p$ by $x^2$ so that $Y_p$ becomes $A{x^2}e^x$

Then, find $Y_p'$ and $Y_p''$ to get:

$2Ae^x = e^{px}$

$2A = 1$

$A= \frac{1}{2}$

Then, $Y_p = \frac{1}{2}x^2e^{px}$

Is this right?

Comment: @graydad I'm pretty sure they mean the particular and complementary solutions

Comment: @graydad Ok I will look into it. Yes $Y_p$ is particular solutions and $Y_c$ is complementary solutions like Dylan said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Your guess for the particular solution depends on the value of $p$. There are two cases to consider

If $p \ne 1$, it's simply $y_p = Ae^{px}$

Otherwise, it's $y_p = Ax^2e^x$

You've only solved the second case.

Comment: Sorry! I had the wrong equation copied down! I'm pretty sure it would make more sense now

Comment: I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Working the differential equation in the most general manner, the particular solution is $$y_p=\frac{e^{p x}}{(p-1)^2}$$ which shows that  the  case of $p=1$ is totally different from the other possible cases just as Dylan pointed it out.

Comment: it doesn't though. The $p=1$ solution has a different form

Comment: @Dylan. This is what I was meaning when I was quoting you. I shall edit to make the statement clearer.